# Using 'str' type variable to make a range in Python

Tags: python-3.x, multidimensional-array, colors

```
[['5', ' ', '5'],
['1', ' ', '1', ' ', '1', ' ', '1', ' ', '1']...]
```

Risking to be downvoted but this looks just so weird and  I don't know what to even search about... Anyway This is a part of my multidimensional list representing a maze. I'm trying to use the value of `mazeList[0][2]` which is str type `'5'`, to be used in a range so I put it with int type cast.

```
listSize = mazeList[0][2]     # mazeList[0][2]='5'
print(type(listSize))         # print <class 'str'>
for i in (0,int(listSize[0])):
    print("hello")            # print "hello" 2 times
```

It printed "hello" only 2 times... which was weird, because this worked fine:

```
someStrVar = '5'
for i in range(0,int(someStrVar)):
    print("hello")        #print "hello" 5 times
```

What am I missing here? It's python 3.5. if it makes a difference. Any help would be very appreciated.

Comment: Do you see **any difference** in two loops you tried? I'm seeing a `range` in one and not in other. Maybe, you missed `range`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to call `range` in the `for` loop. Instead, you created a tuple with 2 elements which is why the loop only repeats twice.

```
listSize = mazeList[0][2]     # mazeList[0][2]='5'
print(type(listSize))         # print <class 'str'>
for i in range(0,int(listSize[0])):
    print("hello")            # print "hello" 2 times
```

Comment: Thank you osdev0 for your kind explanation! I was so careless.

Answer (score 1):

You must use the range function:

```
for i in range(0,int(listSize[0])):
    print("hello")
```

Comment: Thanks sooo much, svr_sum. I'm so embarassed 